# forwarding an entire class with an operator

Tags: c++, templates

I am wondering. I hit a problem and here is a small repoduce. Essentially i want to forward everything. The problem is, using the first << will cause an error with `o<<1` (or `o<<SomeUserStruct()`. If i include the second i get errors about it being ambiguous. Is there a way i can write this code so it will use `T&` when it can otherwise uses `T`?

```
#include <iostream>
struct FowardIt{
    template<typename T> FowardIt& operator<<(T&t) { std::cout<<t; return *this; }
    //template<typename T> FowardIt& operator<<(T t) { std::cout<<t; return *this; }
};

struct SomeUserStruct{};

int main() {
    FowardIt o;
    o << "Hello";
    int i=1;
    o << i;
    o << 1;
    o << SomeUserStruct();
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
template<typename T> FowardIt& operator<<(const T&t)
                                        //^^^^^ put const here
```

Make the parameter `const` reference, as shown above. Because temporaries cannot be bound to non-const reference. You don't need to define another function. Just make the parameter `const`, the problem will be solved.

It would also be better  if you make the function template `const` as well by putting `const` to the rightmost side of the function as:

```
template<typename T> 
const FowardIt& operator<<(const T&t) const
^^^^^                      ^^^^^      ^^^^^
  |                          |          |
  |                          |          put const here as well
  |                          put const here
  |
  You've to make the return-type also const
  since it can't return non-const reference anymore
```

If you do so, then you can call this function on `const` objects as well:

```
void f(const FowardIt &o)//note: inside the function, o is an const object!
{
    o << 1;
    o << SomeUserStruct();
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer. However if i make the method const i have to make the return const as well. Which would be illogical (for regular streams).

Comment: @acidzombie24: Yes. I also added this!

Comment: Do you have any idea what the problem with this is? http://www.ideone.com/fWVG4 hex works so we know functions are being forward. However endl isnt.